What can I do if someone stole something and wants to pay back but moved away
Salam alikum I know someone who stole lots of food and toys from several different places but now he wants to pay back the money but cannot return to the places because he moved away what should he do?

If he has no way whatsoever, then he could just repent by praying taubat prayer but it has to be deep from ur heart and he truly regrets it and  Allah SWT will forgave him.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
